# Dictionary from columns' elements and indexe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have table like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| a | [1, 2, 3] |
| b | [4, 1, 2] |

And I want to create dictionary like this using NumPy:

{1: [a, b],

2: [a, b],

3: [a],

4: [b]}

is there a more or less simple way to do this?

Comment: I think you have a typo. Your last key-value pair should be `4: ['a']`

Comment: Why do you want to use numpy? Numpy doesn't do dictionaries really. Dictionaries are a pure Python data type -- you don't need numpy to create a dictionary.

Comment: What type of object is your table? A NumPy matrix? A pandas dataframe?

Comment: Pandas dataframe yes

Answer (score 2):

As long as I know, numpy doesn't support dictionaries, it actually uses Arrays (numpy Arrays), [as you can see here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/whatisnumpy.html).

But there are many ways to achieve the creation of a dict from a pandas dataframe. Well, looping over dataframes is not a good practice [as you can see in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/11115072), so we can use pandas.to_numpy as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': ['a', 'b'], 'col2': [[1,2,3], [4,1,2]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

my_dict = {}
np_array=df.to_numpy()
for row in np_array:
    my_dict.update({row[0]: row[1]})
```

Output:

```
>my_dict: {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 1, 2]}
```

Which is different from the output you wished, but I didn't see the pattern on it. Could you clarity more?

**UPDATED**

To achieve the output you want, one possible way is to iterate over each row then over the values in the list, like this:

```
for row in np_array:
    for item in row[1]:
      if item in my_dict.keys():
          my_dict[item].append(row[0])
      else:
          my_dict.update({item: [row[0]]})
```

Comment: I want to make a dictionary in which the elements of the arrays of column B will be used as keys, and the corresponding values of column A will be used as values.

Comment: I updated the answer to match the output you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Let us try with `explode`

```
d = df.explode('col2').groupby('col2')['col1'].agg(list).to_dict()
Out[206]: {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['a', 'b'], 3: ['a'], 4: ['b']}
```